# Cannot load libglfw even when installed

Tags: shared-library

Please look at following terminal extract:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libglfw2 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglfw2 is already the newest version (2.7.9-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
$ ./NecroDancer
./NecroDancer: error while loading shared libraries: libglfw.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have installed lib, but a program cannot detect it. I tried `apt-get update` and to run a program as a `sudo`, but nothing works.
Any hints or help appreciated.

EDIT:

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
$ file ./NecroDancer
./NecroDancer: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=d0e3d623df802578af692c2ead3533c41f2624aa, not stripped
$ ldd ./NecroDancer
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77e0000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0xf774b000)
    ./fmod/lib/libfmodex.so (0xf75c4000)
    libglfw.so.2 => not found
    libopenal.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopenal.so.1 (0xf754c000)
    libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0xf7543000)
    libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0xf7517000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf74fa000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7382000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf732d000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7310000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf715a000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xf7130000)
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0xf712b000)
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0xf7127000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0xf711f000)
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0xf711c000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0xf7100000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf70ea000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0xf70e6000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xf70df000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0xf70dc000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf6f91000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0xf6f75000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0xf6f6f000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf6f49000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xf6f42000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0xf6f30000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf6f2a000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf6f21000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x56587000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf6f1d000)
```

Comment: What are the results of `uname -m`, `file ./NecroDancer`, and `ldd ./NecroDancer`?

Comment: @steeldriver I updated question with output of commands

Comment: Right - so you are trying to run a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit system: you will need to install the 32-bit version of libglfw2